# Converting an array of LatLngs into an an array of simple arrays in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Obtaining an array of `LatLng` objects from a `Polyline` is easy enough, just use `getLatLngs()`, which returns a `LatLng[]`:

```
[  LatLng(45.51, -122.68), LatLng(37.77, -122.43), LatLng(34.04, -118.2)  ]
```

But how do you obtain an array of simple arrays? Something like:

```
[  [45.51, -122.68], [37.77, -122.43], [34.04, -118.2]  ]
```

Or how do you convert an array of `LatLng` objects into an array of simple arrays?

Answer (score 1):

I would project each element of `LatLng[]` into the desired form via [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
points.map(point => [point.lat, point.lng]);
```

The JavaScript code above converts `LatLng[]` to a jagged array.